# How to order results in table row

Tags: html, html-table, prestashop, rows

I am trying to do something, but I can't.
I have a table where the results are like this:

```
+----------+
|Dressing 1|
+----------+
|Dressing 2|
+----------+
|Dressing 3|
+----------+
|Dressing 4|
+----------+
|Dressing 5|
+----------+
|Dressing 6|
+----------+
|Dressing 7|
+----------+
|Dressing 8|
+----------+
|Dressing 9|
+----------+
```

But I want it to display it like this:

```
+----------+----------+----------+
|Dressing 1|Dressing 2|Dressing 3|
+----------+----------+----------+
|Dressing 4|Dressing 5|Dressing 6|
+----------+----------+----------+
|Dressing 7|Dressing 8|Dressing 9|
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Right now, I have a code like this:

```
<table cellpadding="6" border=0>

<tr style="height:20px">

{foreach from=$group.attributes name=awp_loop item=group_attribute}

{strip}

{assign var='id_attribute' value=$group_attribute.0}

<td align="center" {if $group.group_layout}valign="top"{/if}>
<div id="awp_checkbox_cell{$id_attribute}" style="{if !$group.group_layout}float:left;{else}width:100%;clear:left;{/if}">

{if $group.group_per_row > 1}<center>{/if}

<input style="border:none;margin:0;padding:0" type="checkbox" {if $group.attributes_quantity.$id_attribute == 0 && $awp_out_of_stock == 'disable'}disabled="disabled"{/if} class="awp_attribute_selected awp_group_class_{$group.id_group}" name="awp_group_{$group.id_group}" id="awp_checkbox_group_{$id_attribute}" onclick="awp_select('{$group.id_group|intval}',{$group_attribute.0|intval}, {$awp_currency.id_currency},false);" value="{$group_attribute.0|intval}" {if $group.default|is_array && $id_attribute|in_array:$group.default}checked{/if} />&nbsp;

{if $group.group_per_row > 1}</center>{/if}

</div>
</td>

{if $smarty.foreach.awp_loop.iteration < $group.attributes|@count && $smarty.foreach.awp_loop.iteration % $group.group_per_row == 0}

</tr>

<tr style="height:20px;">

{/if}

{/strip}

{/foreach}

</tr>

</table>
```

But I can't figure out how to make the table or the code to only make 3 entries in a row.
If someone could help, it would be great.

Comment: You're checking to see if mod 3 is 0 to start a new row?  What is your code currently producing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a list and float each `li` element left. That would give you your desired result and it would be a lot cleaner.

http://jsfiddle.net/Zppya/

As for your table method... add a counter and use the mod/remainder function to determine every third element so you can create a new row.

Comment: I would prefer to only have 3 entries in a row.

Comment: Does my solution not do that?